# Trying to add rows to a Table results in multiple tables

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to add rows to a table when I click a button, I'm using a session so when the page gets loaded again I don't loose the rows I already inserted. But it only inserts one row and then it inserts them in another table down.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {

            GestorBD = new GestorBDT.GestorBD("MSDAORA", "fs", "pass", "oracle");
            cadsql = "SELECT * FROM PCArticulos";
            GestorBD.queryDB(cadsql, "arts", DsGeneral);
            c.loadDropDownList(DDLArticulos, DsGeneral, "arts", "nombre");
        }
        if (Session["TA"] != null)
        {
            tablaPed = (Table)Session["TA"];
            this.Controls.Add(tablaPed);
        }

    }


    protected void btAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Table ta = tablaPed;

        TableRow t = new TableRow();
        TableCell c = new TableCell();
        c.Text = DDLArticulos.SelectedValue.ToString();
        t.Cells.Add(c);

        TableCell c2 = new TableCell();
        c2.Text = TBCantidad.Text;
        t.Cells.Add(c2);

        ta.Rows.Add(t);
        Session["TA"] = ta;
    }
```

[GIF of the execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOisB.gif)

ASPX:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body style="background-color: #FFFFFF">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div style="height: 320px; background-color: #336699" id="DIV">

        <h3>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" ForeColor="White" style="font-weight: 700; font-size: large; font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif" Text="Alta pedidos"></asp:Label>
        </h3>
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" style="font-weight: 700; color: #FFFFFF; font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif" Text="Artículos"></asp:Label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DDLArticulos" runat="server" style="z-index: 1; left: 122px; top: 55px; position: absolute; width: 201px; height: 19px;">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" ForeColor="White" style="font-weight: 700; font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif; z-index: 1; left: 12px; top: 90px; position: absolute" Text="Cantidad"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TBCantidad" runat="server" style="z-index: 1; left: 120px; top: 92px; position: absolute; width: 194px; right: 839px"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="btAgregaT" runat="server" Text="Agregar a la lista" OnClick="btAgregaT_Click" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Borrar Lista" />
        <br />
        <br />

        <asp:Table ID="tablaPed" runat="server" style="color: #FFFFFF; font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif; font-weight: 700; text-align: center;" Width="378px">
            <asp:TableRow runat="server">
                <asp:TableCell runat="server">Articulos</asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell runat="server">Cantidad</asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
        </asp:Table>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please share your aspx?

Answer (score 0):

In your Page_Load event, You are adding the table altogether as a new control to your web page. You should be only adding the rows.

Modify the Page_Load event as below,

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (!IsPostBack)
                {

                   GestorBD = new GestorBDT.GestorBD("MSDAORA", "fs", "pass", "oracle");
                   cadsql = "SELECT * FROM PCArticulos";
                   GestorBD.queryDB(cadsql, "arts", DsGeneral);
                   c.loadDropDownList(DDLArticulos, DsGeneral, "arts", "nombre");
                }
                if (Session["TA"] != null)
                {
                    tablaPed.Rows.AddRange(((List<TableRow>)Session["TA"]).ToArray());
                }
            }
```

Modify your click event as below,

```
protected void btAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Table ta = tablaPed;
        TableRow t = new TableRow();
        TableCell c = new TableCell();
        List<TableRow> listTableRows = Session["TA"] != null ? (List<TableRow>)Session["TA"] : new List<TableRow>();

        c.Text = DDLArticulos.SelectedValue.ToString():
        t.Cells.Add(c);

        TableCell c2 = new TableCell();
        c2.Text = TBCantidad.Text:
        t.Cells.Add(c2);

        ta.Rows.Add(t);
        listTableRows.Add(t);
        Session["TA"] = listTableRows;
}
```

This will work as per your requirement. Let me know if you face any issue. You can use viewstate instead of session, if you want to retain the table only in the scope of this page.

Hope this helps!